# Magento user roles - individual sales

Tags: magento-1.7, dashboard, user-roles

We are using Magento CE 1.7.02 with 2 stores (wholesale and retailer) and we got a request from the client to assign roles for the sales team.
The problem is that every sales user is able to see other's users sales.

Is there a plugin, or module that could give each user independent profile, so they can't see any other order than the one the created and don't see the overall sales report for that store?

I have been searching without luck.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "sales reps & dealers" at the magento connect.

Comment: That was term i was asking wrong.
Thanks a lot!
Just in case someone else has the same need:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=sales+reps+%26+dealers&pl=0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just create another user and name it under that specific profile. 
Hope this helps.